# socket.io remove object from array and ensure array update correctly if function ran twice the same time

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I need to remove an object from an array. The issue is that there could be a case where this function is ran at the same time. In that case how can I ensure the array is updated correctly as the function my be called by two different users the same time

```
const rooms = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0];

socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    var filtered = array.filter(e => {
        return e !== socket.id
    })

    console.log("room updated", filtered)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript is a single-threaded language. 2 functions will never run in parallel.

No special precautions are necessary.